# How get Woocommerce all child category from current parent category

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, custom-taxonomy, taxonomy-terms

I want that I have some product categories on one page when I click on them, then I should get her child's categories. and I want that this work should be complete on the single page not more than pages 
How can i do this work

Comment: Your question title is clear, but your question body is not… Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once.

Answer (score 0):

Simply add your parent term_id in your get_terms query to fetch all its children as follows -

```
$cat_args = array(
    'orderby'    => 'name',
    'order'      => 'ASC',
    'hide_empty' => false,
    'parent'     => $parent_term_id, // set your parent term id
);

$child_categories = get_terms( 'product_cat', $cat_args );

// since wordpress 4.5.0
$cat_args = array(
    'taxonomy'   => "product_cat",
    'orderby'    => 'name',
    'order'      => 'ASC',
    'hide_empty' => false,
    'parent'     => $parent_term_id, // set your parent term id
);
$child_categories = get_terms($cat_args);
```

It will returns all childs terms objects

Answer (score 0):

You can use WordPress dedicated function [`get_term_children()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_term_children) from a product category term Id:

```
$child_terms_ids = get_term_children( $term_id, 'product_cat' );
```

It return a array of children terms Ids.

---

For product category archive pages, you can use:

```
// get the current product category term ID
if ( is_product_category() ) {
    $term_id = (int) get_queried_object_id();
}

if ( term_exists( $term_id, 'product_cat' ) ) {
    $child_terms_ids = get_term_children( $term_id, 'product_cat' );

    // Loop through child terms Ids
    foreach ( $child_terms_ids as $child_term_id ) {
        $child_term = get_term_by( 'term_id', $child_term_id, 'product_cat' );
        // The term name
        $child_name = $child_term->name;
        // The term link
        $child_link = get_term_link( $child_term, 'product_cat' );
    }
}
```